# Mark cell with X if dates fall within range

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to come up with the formula for this, but am stuck. I have columns A and B, which contain dates (ex: cell A6 is October 6, 2022 and cell B6 is November 14, 2022). Column B may be empty. Columns C-N are January 2022-December 2022. I would like an "X" to show up in the cells that fall under columns C through N if the date(s) in A [and B, if available] fall within the months listed in C-N. C-N may have more than one X. In my example, the X would show up in both cells E6 and F6.

[image: Example of spreadsheet]

Comment: Why does Nov '22 have an X on the second row if both dates are in October?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That was a mistake. I've edited the picture.

Comment: @ScottCraner It's formatted as a date.

Comment: Since you are going over years, A:B should probably be formatted to include the year.

Comment: @ScottCraner That did it. Thank you so much. Just learned about the EOMONTH function, thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in C2:

```
=IF(AND(EOMONTH($A2,0)<=EOMONTH(C$1,0),EOMONTH(IF($B2="",$A2,$B2),0)>=EOMONTH(C$1,0)),"X","")
```

Copy it over and down.

[image]